# ifstream file fails to open C++ Visual studio

Tags: visual-c++

//Made a program to practice exception handling in C++ the code 
executes without error but it will not open the ifstream file and 
extract the dates i have typed. The infile is named "testdates" and          is saved using notepad.

```
    #include "pch.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    bool leapYear(int year);

    class dateType {
    public:
        dateType();
        dateType(int d, int m, int y);
        dateType(const dateType &d);

        void printDate(ostream &os);
        void setDate(int m, int d, int y);
        void checkDate(ostream &os);
    protected:
        int myMonth, myDay, myYear;
    };

    int main() {
        ofstream outfile;
        outfile.open("checkdates.txt");
        ifstream infile;
        infile.open("testdates.txt");
```

// ^^ I already created this with dates to be read. ^^

```
        if (infile.fail()) {
            cout << "file location not found";
            system("pause");
            return 1;
        }
        outfile << "John L" << endl << endl;
        cout << "John L" << endl << endl;

        int d, m, y;
        dateType d1;
        int i = 1;
        while (!infile.eof()) {
            infile >> m >> d >> y;
            d1.setDate(m, d, y);
            d1.checkDate(outfile);
            d1.checkDate(cout);
        }
        system("pause");
        infile.close();
        outfile.close();
        return 0;
    }

    dateType::dateType() {
        myDay = 1;
        myMonth = 1;
        myYear = 0;

    }
    dateType::dateType(int m, int d, int y) {
        myDay = d;
        myMonth = m;
        myYear = y;
    }

    dateType::dateType(const dateType &rhs) {
        myDay = rhs.myDay;
        myMonth = rhs.myMonth;
        myYear - rhs.myYear;
    }
    void dateType::printDate(ostream &os) {
        ofstream outfile;
        outfile << "Date: " << myMonth << "/" << myDay << "/" << myYear << endl;
         cout   << "Date: " << myMonth << "/" << myDay << "/" << myYear << endl;
    }
    void dateType::setDate(int m, int d, int y) {
        myDay = d;
        myMonth = m;
        myYear = y;
    }
    void dateType::checkDate(ostream &os) {

        class badDate {};
        class badDay1 {};
        class badDay2 {};
        class badDay3 {};
        class badDayFeb {};
        class badDayLeap {};
        class badMonth1 {};
        class badMonth2 {};
        class negYear {};
        class goodDate {};

        try {
            if ((myMonth >= 1 && myMonth <= 12) && myDay >= 1 && myYear >= 0) {
                if (myDay > 31)
                    throw badDay1();

                else if ((myMonth == 4 || myMonth == 6 || myMonth == 9 || myMonth == 11) && myDay > 30)
                    throw badDay2();
                else if (myMonth == 2 && myDay > 28 && !leapYear(myYear))
                    throw badDayFeb();
                else if (myMonth = 2 && myDay > 29 && leapYear(myYear))
                    throw badDayLeap();
                else throw goodDate();
            }

            else if (myDay < 1)
                throw badDay3();
            else if (myMonth < 1)
                throw badMonth1();
            else if (myMonth > 12)
                throw badMonth2();
            else if (myYear < 0)
                throw negYear();
        }
        catch (badDay1) {
            os << "Invalid day: no month has more than 31 days " << endl;

        }
        catch (badDay2) {
            os << "Invalid day: Month only has 30 days " << endl;

        }
        catch (badDay3) {
            os << "Invalid day: Days cannot be less than 1" << endl;

        }
        catch (badDayFeb) {
            os << "Invalid day: february only has 28 years unless it is a 
        leap year. " << endl;

        }
        catch (badDayLeap) {
            os << "Invalid day: February has 29 days on a leap year " << 
        endl;

        }
        catch (badMonth1) {
            os << " Invalid month: Month cannot be less than zero " << endl;

        }
        catch (badMonth2) {
            os << "Invalid month: There are only 12 months " << endl;

        }
        catch (negYear) {
            os << "Invalid year: A year cannot be negative " << endl;

        }
        catch (goodDate) {
            os << " This date works! " << endl;

        }
    }
    bool leapYear(int y) {
        return(y % 4 == 0 && y % 100 != 0) || (y % 400 == 0);


   }
```

//the output will end up being   "file location not found" 
I have also tried the full path neither work.

"C:\Users\phill\source\repos\ConsoleApplication25\ConsoleApplication25\testdates.txt"

this is what the file contains

"testdates.txt"
11 27 1998
-50 10 1990
9 -200 1000
4 14 -1
13 9 1452
12 32 2018
2 29 2018
2 29 2020
2 20 2020
11 31 2009

Comment: Did you try double-slash? `"C:\\Users\\phill\\source\\repos\\ConsoleApplication25\\ConsoleApplication25\\testdates.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the text file in the debug folder of your project. Also, if you hold alt and press a name of a file in code, it should open the file.